# Can someone help to solve an error when using content in blazor reference - error 404?

Tags: blazor

Thank-you in advance for help, I may just have a typo or.. ?

in my index.html file in the Organize project i have the following code

I have added the project reference for GeneralUi.

link href="_content/GeneralUi/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"

see screens of folder structure and project inclusion

[image: folder structure]

[image: project reference added]

[image: browser error]

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the solution from visual studio did not work.
I had to manually delete the obj and Bin folders from their respective projects and rebuild and it started working correctly.

Comment: VS also has a "Clean Solution" command on the Build menu.